# i want to create a list that will have all odd numbers replaced with a string

Tags: python, list

i am having issues with the for and if statement but i occasionally get memory error

```
w = 0
x = []

while w < 100:
    if w % 2 != 0:
        x.append('boss')
    else:
        x.append(w)
        w = w+1
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi Tijani, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide more details about the actual problem with an error that you see and how occasionally it occurs? Is your code a sample code of the actual code?

Comment: On the second loop iteration when `w` is 1,  `if w % 2 != 0` becomes true, and it stays true _forever_ because `w` is only incremented in the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me fix your code (`while` statement)

```
w = 0
x = []

while w < 100:
      if w % 2 != 0:
          x.append('boss')
      else:
          x.append(w)
      w = w+1
```

The error is that `w` is always 1, because

1. `w` only added by 1 if w is divisible by two. Since one is not divisible by two so this code will stop
2. Use `for` statement if you want. The `for` statement is easier than `while` statement. So, the code will be like this

```
x = []
for w in range(100):
      if w % 2 != 0:
          x.append('boss')
      else:
          x.append(w)
```

3. And you can use list comprehension to make it easier but a little bit complex.

```
x = [w if w % 2 != 0 else 'boss' for w in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the w = w+1 line should be outside your "else" so that for every iteration of the while loop the variable would be incremented.

```
w = 0
x = []

  while w < 100:
        if w % 2 != 0:
            x.append('boss')
        else:
            x.append(w)
        w = w+1
```

By the way, you could use list comprehension to do that easily (this code generates exactly the same list):

```
x = [val if not val % 2 else 'boss' for val in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
w = 100
x = []
for i in range(w+1):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        x.append('boss')
        continue
    x.append(i)
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['boss' if w % 2 != 0 else w for w in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the str() function to convert it to string and increment the w whether it is odd or even. So place it in the first indent of while not in if.

```
w = 0
x = []

while (w < 100):
    if w % 2 != 0:
        x.append(str(w))
    else:
        x.append(w)
w += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the posts before me have already explained, the issue was with where you were incrementing 'w'. Alternatively you could use 'w' in a for loop without having to explicitly increment it.

Here is a shorter version using list comprehension:

```
x = [("boss" if w%2!=0 else w) for w in range(100)]
```